# stuck in concept of auto layout in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout

I just started to learn auto layout.

I have switched **off** the `Use Size Classes`.

I make there `UILabels` which is shown in the image and their `constraints` also.  I want to look similar in 4s,5s,6 and 6Plus.

But it is working fine on 4s and 5s but distorts in 6 and 6Plus.

Why this is happening and how can I resolve this.

My StoryBoard with constraints:

[image]

Output iN 5s
[image]

Output IN 6 and 6Plus

[image]
[image]

Comment: right now it appears that you haven't done enough reading on the subject matter. Nevertheless, what is it that you're trying to achieve here? You want label1, label3 on the sides and label2 centre aligned?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the way labels are placed in 5s is what you are really looking for, place the constraints as follows :

1. Pin width of all labels equally.
2. Pin Height of all labels
3. Pin vertical position of all labels from top margin equally.
4. Now, as for the problem, add the constraints as follows for horizontal placement of labels : 
   [leading margin--0--label1--40--label2--<=20--label3--Trailing margin]

Adding the horizontal constraints should work for all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because none of your constraints is hooked to the leading/trailing layout guide. What you'll want to do is to attach labels 1 & 3 to the "sides" of the view, and then attaching label 2's constraints accordingly. (I would recommend adding a center horizontally constraint, but it can be achieved by different ways).